# The output of git clone

Tags: git

There are a few things I don't understand about the output of git clone. In the following example :

```
Cloning into 'omap-kernel'...
remote: Counting objects: 2649896, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (418466/418466), done.
remote: Total 2649896 (delta 2218148), reused 2636767 (delta 2205019)
Receiving objects: 100% (2649896/2649896), 575.45 MiB | 4.76 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (2218148/2218148), done.
```

What does `objects`, `delta` and `reused` mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Git stores everything in objects (thing like blobs, trees, commits). The *Pro Git* book has a great introduction chapter ([Git Internals](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Internals)) on the topic. The section about [Git Objects](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Internals-Git-Objects) is a great tutorial on how to create those by hand, and how git operates with those resources.

The *total* and *reused* info are displayed because git also compresses the data (see the descrioption of `git gc` for the details). Otherwise there were quite a lot of redundancy in the repository.